# SQLite: select multiple ids with manual order

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I want to select multiple Ids but in my order. for example:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN (3,1,4)
```

I want the order to be:
3
1
4
same as my query.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement for your order by.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN (3,1,4)
ORDER BY 
CASE 
WHEN id = 3 THEN 1
WHEN id = 1 THEN 2
WHEN id = 4 THEN 3
END
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `instr()`:

```
order by instr(',3,1,4,', ',' || id || ',')
```