# Python sqlite3 - sorting table by day of the week column

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a table where one of the columns has different days for its entries (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc) and I want to organize my table by day so that the rows with Monday for that column are first followed by the rest of the days.

The function I have so far is:

```
import sqlite3
from tabulate import tabulate
conn = sqlite3.connect("Table.db")
c = conn.cursor()

def order_by_day():
    days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
    with conn:
        for i in days:
            data = c.execute("SELECT * FROM Table_name WHERE Day_column=?", (i,))
            print(tabulate(data, headers="keys", tablefmt="grid", stralign='center', numalign='center'))
```

This function works but it creates 7 separate tables for each day of the week instead of one table (the print(tabulate()) function makes the table neat and organized instead of if I used fetchall() so my tables look like the following below).

```
+--------+---------------+-------------+
|  Col1  |      Col2     | Day_column  |
+========+===============+=============+
```

Is there any way I can modify my function so that it creates a single table containing all of my data organized by day instead of 7 separate tables for each day?

Comment: You mean the `tabulate` function?

Comment: you should modify your sql query so that it doesn't only select for a specific day. Then you don't need to have the `for i in days:` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print everything in one output you could try

```
import sqlite3
from tabulate import tabulate
conn = sqlite3.connect("Table.db")
c = conn.cursor()

def order_by_day():
    with conn:
        data = c.execute("SELECT * FROM Table_name ORDER BY Day_column")
        print(tabulate(data, headers="keys", tablefmt="grid", stralign='center', numalign='center'))
```

An additional syntax I found [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366804/sqlite-select-multiple-ids-with-manual-order)

```
import sqlite3
from tabulate import tabulate
conn = sqlite3.connect("Table.db")
c = conn.cursor()

def order_by_day():
    with conn:
        data = c.execute("""SELECT * FROM Table_name ORDER BY Day_column CASE 
                                                                         WHEN Day_column='Monday' THEN 1
                                                                         WHEN Day_column='Tuesday' THEN 2                                                                             
                                                                         WHEN Day_column='Wednesday' THEN 3
                                                                         WHEN Day_column='Thursday' THEN 4
                                                                         WHEN Day_column='Friday' THEN 5
                                                                         WHEN Day_column='Saturday' THEN 6
                                                                         WHEN Day_column='Sunday' THEN 7
                                                                         END""")
        print(tabulate(data.fetchall(), headers="keys", tablefmt="grid", stralign='center', numalign='center'))
```

Comment: Is there a way to use ORDER BY to have it in a certain order? Your way orders it in alphabetical order (so Friday, Monday, Saturday, Sunday, Thursday, Tuesday, Wednesday) but I want to be in order of the days of the week. I was originally going to use that method but I couldn't find anything on it that would let me order it the way I wanted it to be (besides adding numbers to each day such as 1 - Monday, 2 - Tuesday, etc and ordering it by number in  descending order).

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to order it properly and have it display as one table. I ordered it by the days of the week manually as shown.

```
import sqlite3
from tabulate import tabulate
conn = sqlite3.connect("Table.db")
c = conn.cursor()

def order_by_day():
    with conn:
        data = c.execute("""SELECT * FROM Table_name ORDER BY Day_column='Monday'    DESC,
                                                              Day_column='Tuesday'   DESC,
                                                              Day_column='Wednesday' DESC,
                                                              Day_column='Thursday'  DESC,
                                                              Day_column='Friday'    DESC,
                                                              Day_column='Saturday'  DESC,
                                                              Day_column='Sunday'    DESC""")
        print(tabulate(data, headers="keys", tablefmt="grid", stralign='center', numalign='center'))
```

I'm sure there is a better way to go about ordering it but I think it is fine this way to me.